# Laravel - Nexmo Sent SMS to

Tags: php, laravel, sms, vonage

I try to sent sms with this code

[image]

But this work only when i replace $number with a string number like '0306977777777'. I dont know why convert my variable ($number) to a random characters.

$number = '0306977777777'

and i gote this error.

[image]

Comment: Why do you post images instead of searchable and copyable text?

Comment: Well its clearly not a number, you need to debug and figure out why. We can't do that based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code isn't handling the $number correctly, as earlier comments pointed out you need to debug whatever is setting $number.

One thing I did notice though is that with Nexmo you need to send numbers in international format so for Greece the number should be `306977777` without the leading zero otherwise your SMS won't be accepted

Comment: I Fixed, It's my fault. 
I stammered variables and i give them a random number :P